# Would twisted be a good choice for building a multi-threaded server?

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted

I need to pull from hundreds of pop3 email accounts, and i want to build a robust server to do this.

Would twisted be a good choice for this type of project?

Right now a simple prototype would be to pull from a single pop3 account, then it would pull from many but it would be a serialized process.

I want to create a server that has multiple threads so it can do things at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twisted is an event-driven networking framework written in Python. It builds heavily on asynchronous and non-blocking features and is best conceived to develop networking applications that utilizes these. It has thread support for use cases where you can not provide for asynchronous non-blocking I/O. This is based on the fact that most of time is spent waiting in network I/O operations.

The two model that exploits this is threading model where you create multiple threads, each accomplishing a single task or a single process that uses non-blocking I/O to accomplish multiple task in a single process by interleaving multiple tasks. Twisted is very suitable for the second model.

Non-Blocking model

```
+--------------------------+
|task1 | wait period | comp|
+--------------------------+
       +--------------------------+
       |task2 | wait period | comp|
       +--------------------------+
```

You can develop a very robust server with Twisted and it has POP3 / IMAP support.

There is an example of how to build [pop3 client with twisted](http://openp2p.com/pub/a/python/2006/08/10/untwisting-python-network-programming.html?page=last&x-maxdepth=0).

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the majority of your POP3 activity is going to be network I/O, this is where Twisted excels. You're not really threading so much as performing event-based asynchronous socket operations, which is the crowning glory of Twisted.

So, yes, Twisted would be a good choice for this type of project. It can do client and server operations equally well and it is almost trivial to spin up a new async TCP client and it already has a [POP3 TCP Client](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.0.0/api/twisted.mail.pop3client.html) available by default.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good choice for a server but from your description you are acutally looking for a multithreaded POP client.

Twisted is made for reacting to events like incoming requests, you need to send requests, so in this case I fear twisted to be of limited value.

Comment: Not at all.  A client and a server aren't really all that different when it comes down to the network layer.

Answer (score -1):

A word of caution with twisted, while twisted is very robust I've found that spinning up a hundred threads using the code examples available in documentation is a recipe for race conditions and deadlocks. My suggestion is try twisted but have the stdlib multithreading module waiting in the wings if twisted becomes unmanageable. I have had good success with a producer consumer model using the aforementioned library.

Comment: Twisted is neither more nor less prone to race conditions when threading is involved.  What's great about Twisted is the ability to do so many things *without* threads.  And actually, helpers like twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread actually do take a small bit of the misery out of threading. ;)

Comment: It's the model I am pointing to that I think is easier to understand, easier to debug, and generally has less issue than twisted. I am not trying to make the argument that one library is better than the other. I agree the technical merits of twisted are superior but thats not the only reason to use a framework.