# where to start programing a server application

Tags: python

Question: Where is a good starting point for learning to write server applications?

---

Info:

I'm looking in to writing a distributed computing system to harvest the idle cycles of the couple hundred computers sitting idle around my college's campus. There are systems that come close, but don't quite meet all the requirements I need. (most notable all transactions have to be made through SSH because the network blocks everything else)  So I've decided to write my own application. partly to get exactly what I want, but also for experience.

Important features:

1. Written in python
2. All transaction made through ssh(this is solved through the simple use of pexpect)
3. Server needs to be able to take potentially hundreds of hits. I'll optimize later, the point being simulation sessions.

I feel like those aren't to ridiculous of things to try and accomplish. But with the last one I'm not certain where to even start. I've actually already accomplished the first 2 and written a program that will log into my server, and then print ls -l to a file locally. so that isn't hard. but how do i attach several clients asking the server for simulation data to crunch all at the same time? obviously it feels like threading comes in to play here, but more than that I'm sure.

This is where my problem is. Where does one even start researching how to write server applications? Am I even using the right wording? What information is there freely available on the internet and/or what books are there on such? again, specifically python, but a step in the right direction is one more than where i am now.

p.s. this seeemed more fitting for stackoverflow than serverfault. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: that looks like almost exactly what i was looking for. can you provide a little more direction and put that as an answer? ^_^

Comment: Any answer to this question would be too broad for SO format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the following discussion on SO

- [Would twisted be a good choice for building a multi-threaded server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629088/would-twisted-be-a-good-choice-for-building-a-multi-threaded-server)

Also check out the fantastic introductions at

- Twisted Introduction : http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327
- Twisted Web in 60 seconds : http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/50562.html

Answer (score 1):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) is an event loop framework that is commonly used in Python for network handling.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach.

1. Write an "agent" in Python.  The agent is installed on the various computers.  It does whatever processing your need locally.  It uses `urllib2` to make RESTful HTTP requests of the server.  It either posts data or requests work to do or whatever is supposed to go on.
2. Write a "server" in Python.  The server is installed on one computer.  This is written using `wsgiref` and is a simple WSGI-based server that serves requests from the various agents scattered around campus.

While this requires agent installation, it's very, very simple.   It can be made very, very secure (use HTTP Digest Authentication).  And the agent's privileges define the level of vulnerability.  If the agent is running in an account with relatively few privileges, it's quite safe.  The agent shouldn't run as root and the agent's account should not be allowed to `su` or `sudo`.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was a little confusing. This is very useful information, but i was looking to introduction information to writing server applications and used my project as an example. You described though almost exactly what I'm going to do. client installs on (unfortunately) windows machines which request information from the single server. The problem with your proposal is that the campus network will block HTTP requests. ssh is the only permitted network protocol. I suppose I could tunnel, but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it. thanks for the tips.

Comment: @Narcolapser: "the campus network will block HTTP requests"?  Really?  How do you know that?  HTTP is perhaps the single most-used protocol on the planet.  You're saying that no web browsers work?  That there are no web servers anywhere?

Comment: it is a log in system. you may have heard of "Cisco Clean Access Agent"? It is a program you install on your computer (for windows and and mac, java web applet for linux) that checks your registry for up to date updates and anti virus, pushes you to a update quarantine if you are behind to let you up date. the system requires you be logged to the computer and logged in to cisco. using the campus computers w/o login requires "remote access protocol" as they put it which would be RDP, VNC, and SSH. my server obviously has no GUI as well so I can't log into Cisco. so http is blocked. :/

Comment: @Narcolapser: "my server obviously has no GUI as well so I can't log into Cisco. so http is blocked" Makes approximately no sense.  Any computer can be an HTTP server.  Any.  Logging into some random Cisco server has no relevance to creating an application with HTTP and RESTful web services.  Any computer can serve HTTP.  And it's really unlikely that HTTP is blocked because no one could ever use a web browser.

Comment: your not quite getting what Cisco is doing. It is a quarantine system. Your computer is not allowed on to the network (which means yes, you can't use a web browser) UNTIL you log in through Cisco's Clean Access Agent(CAA). My server can work just fine as an HTTP server, it is just that it order for it to do that it would have to be logged into CAA. If it isn't logged in, the everything but the prior mentioned protocol are blocked. The random cisco server controls our ability to access the internet. if we aren't logged in, no Internet. my server runs headless, no gui, no logging in. make sense?

Comment: @narcolapser: "make sense?" Barely.  "My server can work just fine as an HTTP server, it is just that it order for it to do that it would have to be logged into CAA".  So?  What's stopping this?

Comment: "no gui, no logging in."<<< This server is running headless, I control it completely through ssh. The login is a java web applet, and as I cannot run a web applet in command line I can't log in. Because I can't log in all protocol but ssh (and the others) is blocked. The long short of it is that everything but ssh is blocked unless you log in, I can't log in, so only ssh can be used to transfer data.

Comment: @Narcolapser: "I can't log in".  Why not?  Can't you talk to someone about this?

Comment: I can, but I don't have confidence in them giving me a permanent log in on my server. I'm a student and as such I obviously can't be trusted, I might do something malicious or stupid. *sigh* its what I've got to work with. though i just discovered that cross network traffic is not blocked by cisco, only traffic that goes through our internet gateway(probably where the server is) so what you proposed has certain value, thought it technically wasn't what i was asking for. but thanks for the advise! ^_^

Comment: @Narcolapser:  "I don't have confidence in them giving me a permanent log in on my server."  Then get some confidence.  Ask them what the rules are.

Comment: actually, i just found out that there is a professor who is working on a very math intensive project that he frequently leaves his computer on over night to accomplish. With a professor's research behind my ambitions the computing services department will be far more willing. getting the professor on board with me will probably be as easy as "would you be interested in a super computer?" ha! this will be fun. (I've already almost got the system running. ^_^)